# Parse XSL Date Format

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, shopify, xml-formatting

I'm making an XSL stylesheet to format the XML date output by Shopify.

What is output is;

```
<created-at type="dateTime">2014-12-23T14:27:53-05:00</created-at>
```

And I need to adjust it to look like

```
<created-at type="dateTime">2014-12-23 14:27:53</created-at>
```

I'm just not sure how to remove the 'T' or clip the time-zone stamp at the end.

Any suggestions?

Current XSL Stylesheet (Order Date is what I'm trying to adjust);

```
<xsl:template match="order">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>St. Baldrick's Order #<xsl:value-of select="order-number" /></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>
                Order Number: <xsl:value-of select="order-number" /><br /><!-- Their Order Number -->
                Client ID: <xsl:value-of select="id" /><br /><!-- Internal Compass ID or Customer Account Number -->
                First Name: <xsl:value-of select="first-name" /><br /><!-- Ship-to first name -->
                Last Name: <xsl:value-of select="last-name" /><br /><!-- Ship-to last name -->
                Order Date: <xsl:value-of select="created-at" /><br /><!-- Order Date -->
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please show your current XLST stylesheet. Only then we can provide you with an answer that is immediately useful.

Comment: @MathiasMüller I've updated with the XSLT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that would be, just as example for matching the complete node

```
<xsl:template match="created-at">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:attribute name="type" select="@type"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="substring(translate(.,'T', ' '),1,string-length()-6)"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Result: `<created-at type="dateTime">2014-12-23 14:27:53</created-at>`

This replaces the T with a space using `translate()` and cuts of the last 6 characters using `substring()`.

**Update:** As mentioned in the comment, in case the date is always in the format hh:mm:ss, the `string-length()` in the `substring()` can be removed and the select expression simplified to `<xsl:value-of select="substring(translate(.,'T', ' '),1,19)"/>`

For the just added original template matching `order`: It should work if you just change this:

```
Order Date: <xsl:value-of select="created-at" />
```

into this:

```
Order Date: <xsl:value-of select="substring(translate(created-at,'T', ' '),1,19)" />
```

Comment: **1.** There is no `0` position in a string; the first character is at position `1`.   **2.** Assuming the time is in hh:mm:ss format, you could simplify the expression to `substring(translate(., 'T', ' '), 1, 19)`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks for the advice, updated. Regarding 1., it's strange that it worked on the xslt processor I tested with.

Comment: I've tried adding that before & following `<xsl:template match="order">` and in-place of `<xsl:value-of select="created-at" />` but to no avail.  Am I doing this wrong @matthias_h ?

Comment: @Newcombe I've just updated my answer for that, previous answer was just an example matching the single `created-at` element, therefore instead of `created-at` in the `select` it was possible to use a `.` as it was the current node.

Comment: It "works" even with a negative number - but it doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @matthias_h you're a saint!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @michael.hor257k Just tested with negative numbers, as it cuts of characters at the end of the string, it seems to mean something. Your're of course right with starting at 1. Just had a look at http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_substring.html to check if negative start values are taken into account and they are.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything in terms of characters, since there are none in the negative position. But yes, the overall length is relative to the start.